# Calling Visualforce page from Custom List Button?

Tags: custom-button

I am trying to call a Visualforce page from a custom list button.  I have done this successfully from a detail page button by creating a page using a standard controller for the detail object, selecting Visualforce page as the content source and then picking the page I wanted from the pull down list for content.

However, I can't seem to get this to work for a list button.  I pick the list button option on the custom button or link page, and pick visualforce page for the content source, but I don't get my visualforce page to appear in the content pull down list.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use  `recordSetVar` on your page to make it available for custom List view button.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities" tabStyle="Opportunity" extensions="tenPageSizeExt">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock  title="Edit Stage and Close Date" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="opp">
                <apex:column value="{!opp.name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Stage">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.stageName}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Close Date">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.closeDate}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>      
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

[Adding Custom List Buttons using Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm)